# I added my username to /etc/sudoers but using sudo still asks for password

Tags: command-line, sudo

I entered my username in the sudoers file, but when using sudo in scritps, it still asks for the password.

This is my sudoers file:

```
~: ls -al /etc/sudoers
-r--r-----  1 root  wheel  1297 Aug 14 11:44 /etc/sudoers
```

Contents:

```
...
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
petruza ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

(http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=F38RxeYP)
(I also tried with %petruza but didn't work either)

I have a script to start XAMPP, but it asks for the password anyway:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please realize that disabling the password prompt for `sudo` is a huge security concern.

However, it is possible. Instead of what you already have, add this to your `/etc/sudoers` file:

`petruza ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

[Here is some more reading on this topic.](https://romkey.com/2008/11/08/use-sudo-without-a-password-on-your-mac/)

Comment: Thanks, I can see this is a security threat, but there's actually no sensible information of which security I should care about.

Comment: You should care because, without a password prompt for `sudo`, a utility can run as a privileged user without you allowing it to or even without you knowing. I think a better option is to use `sudo -v`, which will cache your credentials and extend the `sudo` timeout by 5 minutes. This way, you will be prompted less often but not sacrifice a great deal of security.

Comment: I’ve just found that such a user record must be in `sudoers` **after** the `root` and `%admin` records. It took me a lot of time… :-/